# How do I associate a file extension with a specific mode?

Tags: major-mode

I would like emacs to switch to `gnuplot-mode` when I open a file ending in `.g` or `.gnuplot`.

I tried

```
;; gnuplot mode-name
(add-to-list 'gnuplot-mode '("\\.g\\'" . gnuplot-mode))
```

or

```
;; gnuplot mode-name
(add-to-list 'gnuplot '("\\.g\\'" . gnuplot))
```

Neither works.  How do I make Emacs behave this way?

Comment: Where is the duplicated (original) question?

Answer (score 34):

The full syntax for specifying file extensions for gnuplot-mode is:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.g\\'" . gnuplot-mode))
```

The other point to verify is that you are using Bruce Ravel's recent (year 2012) implementation of [gnuplot-mode](https://github.com/bruceravel/gnuplot-mode). This is a separate MELPA package that requires gnuplot version 4.4 and higher.

Lastly avoid gnuplot-mode files that come pre-packaged with gnuplot itself. They have not been kept compatible with newer emacs versions.

Comment: You can make that a bit more concise by using `add-to-list`. Also relevant: `C-h i g (elisp) Auto Major Mode`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: since `add-to-list` is probably the canonical idiom, could you add that as a separate answer for future users?