# How do I associate a file such as git's `COMMIT_EDITMSG` with a specific mode?

Tags: git, auto-mode-alist

I was doing following solution for markdown files: [How do I associate a file extension with a specific mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17888/18414)

```el
(autoload 'markdown-mode "markdown-mode.el"
  "Major mode for editing Markdown files" t)

(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.md" . markdown-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

---

I want to do it same operation for text show up when I want to commit a message for git. When I type `git commit` a `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file shows up which has `Fundamental` mode. Since `COMMIT_EDITMSG` does not have any extention I was not able to match it into markdown-mode as I done for `*.md` files.

```
CRM Buffer                 Size Mode             File
.   COMMIT_EDITMSG         1259 Fundamental      ~/folder/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

My `.gitconfig` file setup:

```
[core]
    pager = less -r
    editor = TERM=xterm-256color emacsclient -t
```

**[Q]** Is there a way to open git's `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file in markdown-mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make emacs automatically open binary files in hexl-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/make-emacs-automatically-open-binary-files-in-hexl-mode)

Comment: Seems like an alternative solution. I am not sure will `COMMIT_EDITMSG` or any generated file from `git` at `.git/` without an extention will considered as an binary file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```el
> (setq auto-mode-alist
>       (cons '("\\.md" . markdown-mode) auto-mode-alist))
> ```

That `\\.md` should be `\\.md\\'` otherwise it'll match every filename containing the sequence `.md` anywhere.  (I.e. You already weren't limiting your usage to just matching filename extensions.  For instance `/home/alper/.mdir/foo/bar.c` would match your pattern.)

---

As you can see, the regexps in `auto-mode-alist` are matched against the entire filename, so you can easily use it to match your `COMMIT_EDITMSG` files.

One would normally use `add-to-list` to update the variable:

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("/\\.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'" . markdown-mode))
```

Comment: Updating into `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mdl\\'" . markdown-mode))` fixed it, thanks

Comment: I know this is solved but I am having very wierd behavior. I am using emacs editor to edit commit message. Everythings works all fine. But if I enable magit-diff the `markdown-mode` does not apply to that `COMMIT_EDITMSG`, and git commit fails. Please see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/59387/18414