# Is it possible to force `markdown-mode` during git commit?

Tags: magit, git, markdown-mode

I was using following answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/57535/18414 to set markdown on the `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` file.

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("/\\.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'" . markdown-mode))
```

---

My `.gitconfig` file, to open commit message with `emacs`:

```
[core]
    editor = TERM=xterm-256color emacsclient -t -q
```

---

On my emacs-daemon `magit-git` was enable.

Now during the commit (due to some squash operations in git), I see the commit messag along with the opened `magit-diff:` window.

Example image:

[image]

When I check the `major-mode` it became `Local in buffer COMMIT_EDITMSG; global value is fundamental-mode`.

Afterwards, when I added into `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file and do `C-s C-x`, commit fails and I get following message:

`fatal: could not read commit message: No such file or directory`

But instead if I re-enable `markdown-mode`, save and exit there would be no error.

**[Q]** Is it possible to force `markdown-mode` during git commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a package which is very opinionated about how things with Git should work, so don't be surprised if related Emacs configuration which works *without* Magit gets clobbered when you *do* use Magit.

In this instance, Magit uses `git-commit.el` which provides the variable `git-commit-major-mode` for controlling this.

If you want to control how things happen in Magit, you want to be [checking the Magit documentation](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Commit-Mode-and-Hooks.html) firstly.

Comment: I am little bit lost about how to set `markdown-mode` under `magit-mode-hook`, or is it even possible. If I can't accomplish it, my only option is seems like `Type C-c C-c to finish, or C-c C-k to cancel`

Comment: No need to use a hook to set this variable -- it's not buffer-local.  Just use the `customize` link from `C-h v git-commit-major-mode`, or `setq` it in your init file.

Comment: From customization I only have two options: `0 = text-mode                                                                        1= No major mode` . I setted to no major mode but didn't help

Comment: Yep, just noticed that myself.  That's pretty weird.  You'll have to use this in your init file:  `(setq git-commit-major-mode 'markdown-mode)`

Comment: Now `markdown-mode` is enables on the file but still it generates a error `fatal: could not read commit message: No such file or directory`.  But even mark-down mode seems on when I do `M-x mardown-mode` save and close error is seems gone

Comment: And `major-mode` still seems as `fundamental-mode` :-(

Comment: I don't know what the error issue is, sorry, but I suspect it's nothing to do with setting the major mode.  Re your last comment, if you're referring to the global value then note that `major-mode`'s *global* value will always be `fundamental-mode` -- but the global value of this variable is irrelevant.

Comment: You are right its mode became `markdown-mode`. But i have to do `markdown-mode` under M-x to handle the error. If I will able to solve it , i will update

Comment: Tangentially, I see that the current version of Magit has fixed that `customize` issue for `git-commit-major-mode` (and even includes markdown as a default option).  That alone won't change anything else, but I felt it was worth noting.

Comment: When `emacs` started clean during commit `with-editor-finish` is not detected. I had to run `magit-status` but still `C-c C-c` won't bind to `with-editor-finish` on the buffer for `COMMIT_EDITMSG`